# how to stop the phone from usb charging for HTC nexus one model

Tags: android, linux

I'm trying to disable charging when connected to USB port  model HTC nexus one  rooted device(android version 2.3.3) using command setprop persist.usb.chgdisabled 1.But its not working .

is there any other way?.

Answer (score 0):

`/sys/class/power_supply/battery/` which has some information about charging.`charging_enabled` gives the information about charging status. 0 is not enabled and 1 is enabled.Try to change it, it may work.

`$ adb shell
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/charging_enabled
1`

Comment: I have tried adb shell $ cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/charging_enabled, But its not working in productions builds.Please suggest.Thanks